# SELECT DISTINCT returns more rows than expected

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have read many answers here, but until now nothing could help me. I'm developing a ticket system, where each ticket has many updates.

I have about 2 tables: `tb_ticket` and `tb_updates`.

I created a SELECT with subqueries, where it took a long time (about 25 seconds) to get about 1000 rows. Now I changed it to `INNER JOIN` instead many `SELECT`s in subqueries, it is really fast (70 ms), but now I get duplicates tickets. I would like to know how can I do to get only the last row (ordering by time).

My current result is:

```
...
67355;69759;"COMPANY X";"2014-08-22 09:40:21";"OPEN";"John";1
67355;69771;"COMPANY X";"2014-08-26 10:40:21";"UPDATE";"John";1
```

The first column is the **ticket ID**, the second is the **update ID**... I would like to get only a row per ticket ID, but DISTINCT does not work in this case. Which row should be? Always the latest one, so in this case **2014-08-26 10:40:21**.

**UPDATE:**
It is a postgresql database. I did not share my current query because it has only portuguese names, so I think it would not help at all.

**SOLUTION:**
**Used_By_Already** had the best solution to my problem.

Comment: Would be shiny, if you could give us your SQL statement to work with

Comment: Your tables are prefixed 'tb_'. Out of interest, are your stored procedures prefixed 'sp_'?

Comment: Without table structure and a copy of the SQL that you need fixed... we really cannot help you.

Comment: `DISTINCT` always applies to **all the columns returned** - no row should have **all the same values** - that's what `DISTINCT` does - nothing else.

Comment: Hi, it a postgresql and I have no SP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the details of your tables one has to guess the field names, but it seems that tb_updates has many records for a single record in tb_ticket (a many to one relationship).

A generic solution to your problem - to get just the "latest" record - is to use a subquery on tb_updates (see alias mx below) and then join that back to tb_updates so that only the record that has the latest date is chosen.

```
SELECT
      t.*
    , u.*
FROM tb_ticket t
      INNER JOIN tb_updates u
                  ON t.ticket_id = u.ticket_id
      INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        ticket_id
                      , MAX(updated_at) max_updated
                  FROM tb_updates
                  GROUP BY
                        ticket_id
            ) mx
                  ON u.ticket_id = mx.ticket_id
                        AND u.updated_at = mx.max_updated
;
```

If you have a dbms that supports ROW_NUMBER() then using that function can be a very effective alternative method, but you haven't informed us which dbms you are using.

---

by the way:
These rows ARE distinct:

```
67355;69759;"COMPANY X";"2014-08-22 09:40:21";"OPEN";"John";1
67355;69771;"COMPANY X";"2014-08-26 10:40:21";"UPDATE";"John";1
```

69759 is different to 69771, and that is enough for the 2 rows to be `DISTINCT`
there are difference in the 2 dates also.

distinct is a `row operator` which means is considers the entire row, not just the first column, when deciding which rows are unique.

Comment: Even with poor information that I gave, you could solve my problem completly. It is incredible! Thank you very much, it works perfectly! Thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Unfortunately, what you don't understand is that SO is not here just to solve your problems, but to pose clear problems and solutions that may help others like you (or me) in the future. A good question does not provide "poor information".

Answer (score 1):

Used_By_Already's solution would work just fine. I'm not sure on the performance but another solution would be to use cross apply, though that is limited to only a few DBMS's.

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_ticket ticket
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT top(1) *
    FROM tb_updates details
    ORDER BY updateTime desc
    WHERE details.ticketID = ticket.ticketID
    ) updates
```

Comment: in fact it would protect against getting more than 1 record if there is a tie on the updatedTime value. But, @Kiklion I'd probably suggest row_number() before cross apply as it is more broadly available.

Answer (score 0):

U Can try something like below if your updateid is identity column:

```
Select ticketed, max(updateid) from table
group by ticketed
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain last row you have to end your query with `order by time desc` then use `TOP (1)` in the select statement to select only the first row in the query result

ex:

```
select TOP (1) .....
       from .....
       where .....
       order by time desc
```